# How to set maximum value of progressbar in Android

Tags: android, onclick, progress-bar

I want to set the maximum value of a `ProgressBar` in Android.

I know I can set the current progress with `setProgress` or `android:progress`, but how do I set the maximum value?

Comment: did you take a look to the ProgressDialog's documentation?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 20):

By default, the progress bar is full when it reaches 100.
If necessary, you can adjust the maximum value (the value for a full bar) using the android:max attribute

`android:max`

Defines the maximum value the progress can take.

Must be an integer value, such as "100".

This may also be a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a value of this type.

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:max="42"  <--- it's the answer)
    android:progress="0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_header_relativelayout"
/>
```

or
`probressbar.setMax(Value);`

Answer (score 3):

you can set progressbar by two way

```
probressbar.setMax(maxValue);
```

or from in xml

```
<ProgressBar
     android:max="maxvalue"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the following:

```
progressbar.setMax(maxValue);
```

Take a look at the API for ProgressBars [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setMax%28int%29).