# How to set max value of a progressbar greater than 100 in android

Tags: android

I am making a stopwatch. I want to show a `ProgressBar` as the time is passed. Currently I am dealing with milliseconds. The max value for the `ProgressBar` is `79200000`. The stopwatch will go from `1` to `79200000`. I want to update the `ProgressBar` with the latest value given from the stopwatch. How can I achieve this?

This is my layout:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/puzzleProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:max="79200000"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
```

This is how I am setting the progress programmatically. This code is working fine if I am using a max value of 100:

```
int time = (int) (timer.getElapsedTimeMili());
progressBar.setProgress(time);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12616269/2900127

Comment: use multiplication factor 79200000/100 as progress bar can have max 100 progress. However i am not sure about the max attribute.

Comment: so now you have to call `progressBar.setProgress(progress)` where progress is in range [0..79200000]

Comment: Even I am struggling to scale down this large number to a range of 1..100

Comment: you dont have to use range 0.100 - this is why `android:max` was introduced

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "it's not working"? That time span is several hours, did you test a large enough range that you would have even seen it move? What happens if you call setProgress(39600000)?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ProgressBar`'s maximum value like so:

```
<ProgressBar
    ...
    android:max="79200000"/>
```

Comment: But this is not working. ProgressBar is not getting updated.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: did you call progressBar.setProgress(i) where i <= 79200000 anywhere in your code? this should show progress in your ProgressBar view.

Comment: Yes I did. I even tested that with a small value and its working. But with this large value. Its not :(

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: if you log the value of your variable ```time``` everytime you call setProgress, what values do you get?

Answer (score 0):

For values surpassing 100, maybe this

```
int progress = ((i / (float) count) * 100)
```

where *i* is the current item being counted and *count* being the total items being looped through

Borrowed it from this *Async* example

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask