# How can I pass an integer variable to my activity's xml file?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a progress bar in Android Studio where the maximum value is dynamically selected based off data in a table that I have. In a class, I create a global variable and set this to be an integer.

I want to then read this in my layout.xml file, so I can have dynamically changing progress bars. Ie something like:

```
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/determinateBar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:progress="67"
    android:max= // IntVariable here />
```

How can I pull a variable from a class into this file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set maximum value of progressbar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12616269/how-to-set-maximum-value-of-progressbar-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the progress bar value programmatically like this

In an activity

```
ProgressBar progressBarView = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
// later when you want to set the value
progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus)
```

or in a fragment

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_example, container, false);
ProgressBar progressBarView = root.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
// later when you want to set the value
progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus)
```

Comment: This is correct, but you might want to explain where root comes from.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! And for anyone looking at this later, can set the max value by doing 'progressBarView.setMax(maxValue);'

Answer (score 1):

You have two different ways to achieve what you want, first is the recommended way that would be to enable data binding in your project by adding this to your app-level build.gradle file inside the android tag:

```
dataBinding {
       enabled = true
}
```

Then you must add the presenter of the activity (that holds the variable you want) to the activity's layout XML like this:

```
<data>

      <variable
           name="presenter"
           type="com.main.TheNameOfYourPresenter" />

</data>
```

Finally, you can use the value stored in your presenter in the progress bar like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/determinateBar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:progress="67"
    android:max="@{presenter.someIntStoredInThePresenter}"/>
```

The second way is to change it programmatically by accessing the progress bar inside your activity class and setting the max attribute as you want it:

```
progressBar.setMax(someInt);
```